# get resource utilization before last restart and a certain time in linux

Tags: linux

How can I get cpu, memory, io usage of any certain time in linux. As an example, I restarted my linux box five minute ago but I need resource utilization data of previous day on 09:10:30.

Comment: Maybe you can add cronjob which get required information every 10 minutes lets say and write it somewhere to the file system?

Comment: @SvetlinTonchev such a thing already exists, it's called `sysstat`.

Comment: That might be a solution. Is there anything better? Does linux stores it some other way? 'sar' is pretty likely but it does not work after restart.

Comment: It Worked, 'sar' is the solution.  in /var/log/sa there are number of files named saXX which denotes date. use the following command to get statistics: #sar -f /var/log/sa/sa23

Answer (score 0):

'sar' is the solution. in /var/log/sa there are number of files named saXX where 'XX' denotes date. use the following command to get statistics of 23rd of this month: #sar -f /var/log/sa/sa23